# pass jsp parameter to another using button

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, button

so i'm trying to pass selected value from a combobox in a jsp to another jsp here is what i got myself into

```
<form name="ff" method="post">  
         <select name='mat' id='soflow'>
        <% ArrayList<Matiere> listeM = MatiereListe.GetMatiere(); %>
       <option></option>
        <% for (Matiere d : listeM)
        { %>
            <option value= <%=d.getCode_mat() %> >
                     <%=d.getLib_mat() %>
            </option>
        <% } %>
         </select>
         <input type=submit value=valider  />
        <br>
        </form>
         <button onclick="window.location.href='/acceuil.jsp?mat=' JSGetSelectedItemMat() " >Statistique</button>
<script>
        function JSGetSelectedItemMat()
        {
            var e = document.getElementById("soflow");
            var strSel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById("btt").value = strSel;    
        } 
        </script>
```

Comment: what do you want to do with this code? I think you are trying to show result on same page?

Comment: im in page called index and trying to pass a selescted item to another page called acceuil.jsp using a button

Comment: as there are two button in you code. It is possible to use only one button to do above task?

Comment: im using two buttons each one should take a specific page but im kind of stuck in the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code to get selected valued from select tag. As there is no need to use js, you are using post method in your html form. Also get the value in `acceuil.jsp` using `getParameter` method. that is `request.getParameter("mat");`

```
<form action="acceuil.jsp" name="ff" method="post">  
         <select name='mat' id='soflow'>
        <% ArrayList<Matiere> listeM = MatiereListe.GetMatiere(); %>
       <option></option>
        <% for (Matiere d : listeM)
        { %>
            <option value= <%=d.getCode_mat() %> >
                     <%=d.getLib_mat() %>
            </option>
        <% } %>
         </select>
         <input type=submit value=valider  />
        <br>
        </form>
```